# R does not obey ggplot2 file saving instructions when inside a loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, graphics

I have a loop that iterates twice, in each iteration generating a graphic and writing it to a png file. It worked up until yesterday. Then, yesterday, after making a few unrelated changes (I can't remember what they were) it stopped working. To be specific, it doesn't crash or even generate a warning, it just doesn't create the png file as requested.

However, if I manually set the looping variable i to 1 or 2 and then select and execute just the code inside the loop, it works.

I cannot work out why this strange behaviour occurs. I thought it might be to do with Rstudio, but I tried it without Rstudio, both running from the linux command line, and running it from the R command line via the source() command, and in both cases the result was the same.

I hope somebody can suggest what is going wrong.

I am using R version 3.3.1, via Rstudio version 1.0.136, on Linux Mint on a 64-bit PC. R packages used include gridExtra, gridGraphics, gtable and png.

Here is the loop:

```
for (i in 1:2){
  temp<-subset(graph.dat,qtr.index==i)
  png(paste(output_dir,'3.',c('a','b')[i],'.G.png',sep=''),width=1800,height=1152)  
# Open file to write graph to. Save as 3.a.G in first iteration and 3.b.G in the second
  print(i)
  ggplot() +
    geom_bar(data = temp, aes(x=Customer, y=pmax(0,Amount), fill=Category),stat = "identity",width=0.5) + 
# this line plots the bars above the zero line
    geom_bar(data = temp, aes(x=Customer, y=pmin(0,Amount), fill=Category),stat = "identity",width=0.5) + 
# this line plots the bars below the zero line
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "Paired") +
    labs(x='',y='Provision for tax')+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-15000, 15000))+
    geom_point(data=subset(Estimate,qtr.index==i), aes(x=Customer, y=Amount),size=13,shape=15)+ 
# this line plots the point markers
    ggtitle(paste('Stocktake - ',dates.df$dates.short[i],sep=''))
  dev.off() 
# Now save the graph to a .png file
}
```

Here is the data. It's a data frame with only 72 rows:

```
"Category"  "Customer"  "qtr.index" "Amount"
"Stock" "Cust 1"    "2" -2178.34975
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 1"    "2" -1307.11426
"Other Income"  "Cust 1"    "2" -4556.12196
"Revenue"   "Cust 1"    "2" 2797.16517
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 1"    "2" 4283.00036
"Receivables"   "Cust 1"    "2" 388.23353
"Stock" "Cust 3"    "2" -133.7925
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 3"    "2" -1056.23411
"Other Income"  "Cust 3"    "2" -46.64558
"Revenue"   "Cust 3"    "2" 75.5956
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 3"    "2" 1747.73888
"Receivables"   "Cust 3"    "2" -625.0622
"Stock" "Cust 4"    "2" -366.3761465
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 4"    "2" -42.9030924
"Other Income"  "Cust 4"    "2" -225.5160776
"Revenue"   "Cust 4"    "2" 150.7087336
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 4"    "2" 7.2424856
"Receivables"   "Cust 4"    "2" 489.100618
"Stock" "Cust 6"    "2" -1944.27337910587
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 6"    "2" -719.491754021401
"Other Income"  "Cust 6"    "2" -3506.80597312394
"Revenue"   "Cust 6"    "2" 2377.06949826214
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 6"    "2" 6272.82876949579
"Receivables"   "Cust 6"    "2" -3128.20591286837
"Stock" "Cust 7"    "2" -3143.20946024247
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 7"    "2" -1191.70611887001
"Other Income"  "Cust 7"    "2" -4947.00046655931
"Revenue"   "Cust 7"    "2" 3672.57987260769
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 7"    "2" 5057.1723408229
"Receivables"   "Cust 7"    "2" -1777.46732478221
"Stock" "Cust 5"    "2" -3096.57633
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 5"    "2" -1489.33705
"Other Income"  "Cust 5"    "2" -1788.19689
"Revenue"   "Cust 5"    "2" 2586.39059
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 5"    "2" 1974.36526
"Receivables"   "Cust 5"    "2" 754.04481
"Stock" "Cust 1"    "1" -2248.1011
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 1"    "1" -1406.18579
"Other Income"  "Cust 1"    "1" -4804.24372
"Revenue"   "Cust 1"    "1" 3082.00792
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 1"    "1" 4621.07184
"Receivables"   "Cust 1"    "1" 49.54561
"Stock" "Cust 3"    "1" -125.23352
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 3"    "1" -1010.1423
"Other Income"  "Cust 3"    "1" -50.4339
"Revenue"   "Cust 3"    "1" 75.24065
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 3"    "1" 1604.92511
"Receivables"   "Cust 3"    "1" -558.1197
"Stock" "Cust 4"    "1" -353.344313
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 4"    "1" -41.970828
"Other Income"  "Cust 4"    "1" -195.553684
"Revenue"   "Cust 4"    "1" 154.670712
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 4"    "1" 5.998472
"Receivables"   "Cust 4"    "1" 432.343192
"Stock" "Cust 6"    "1" -1995.81268914429
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 6"    "1" -748.13574488012
"Other Income"  "Cust 6"    "1" -3420.80676167929
"Revenue"   "Cust 6"    "1" 2491.28703802434
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 6"    "1" 5932.08646545911
"Receivables"   "Cust 6"    "1" -2980.3132874941
"Stock" "Cust 7"    "1" -3176.99364830721
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 7"    "1" -1258.21862586926
"Other Income"  "Cust 7"    "1" -5264.98717587913
"Revenue"   "Cust 7"    "1" 4184.60759887337
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 7"    "1" 5555.32857632657
"Receivables"   "Cust 7"    "1" -2362.99537101079
"Stock" "Cust 5"    "1" -3149.18544
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 5"    "1" -1521.17289
"Other Income"  "Cust 5"    "1" -2032.76354
"Revenue"   "Cust 5"    "1" 2807.38446
"Other Expenses"    "Cust 5"    "1" 2236.51582
"Receivables"   "Cust 5"    "1" 677.97416
```

Comment: Auto-printing is disabled in the body of a for loop, so the graphic isn't actually created. You need to manually print your ggplot object.  I'm sure this is a duplicate...

Comment: Read the R-FAQ section 7 item number ... greater than 20 and less than 35 but you should read them all rather than me looking it up .... again.

Comment: @andrew-kirk You need to share the data for the other variables Estimate, dates.df, ... As pointed out by Joshua you need to store the plot in a variable `p <- ggplot()+...` and then print it `print(p)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Joshua and Karthik. That fixed the problem.